# addClass - new class not being recognized

Tags: jquery

I have one text-box. That I'm using for two different entries depending on radio button. When radio-button is selected I change the name attribute and remove old class and add new class (keyup-numeric or keyup-charNumOnly) . Depending on the class there is edit functions performed.Using Chrome DEV Tools, I see the class is changing as expected (back in forth no problem). But the keyup-numeric function is the only one that gets performed. I'm new to JQUERY. So this may be oblivious. 
Thanks for help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#radio1").click(function() {
  $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();
  $("#requestedInput").val("Update Address using Account Number").attr('name','acctNumber').attr('maxlength','10');
  $("#requestedInput").removeClass().addClass('inputNumTextBox keyup-numeric');
 });  
  $("#radio2").click(function() {  
  $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();
   $("#requestedInput").val("Update Account Number using Address").attr('name', 'Address').attr('maxlength','23');
  $("#requestedInput").removeClass().addClass('inputNumTextBox keyup-charNumOnly');
 } );
  
  $('.keyup-numeric').keyup(function() {
  $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();
  var inputVal = $(this).val();
  var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
  var AcctReg9 = /^9/;
  if(!numericReg.test(inputVal)) { 
   $('<p class="error-keyup-1 errorStyle centerText">Numeric characters only</p>').appendTo('#enterRequestDataSection');
  }
  if(!AcctReg9.test(inputVal)) { 
   $('<p class="error-keyup-1 errorStyle centerText">Accounts Start with 9 .... Required</p>').appendTo('#enterRequestDataSection');
  }
  if ($('#requestedInput').val().length==0) {
    $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();   
   }
  }); 
 
 $('.keyup-charNumOnly').keyup(function() {
  alert('keyup-charNumOnly I'); 
  $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();
  var inputVal = $(this).val(); 
  var characterReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
  if(!characterReg.test(inputVal)) { 
   alert('keyup-charNumOnly II'); 
   $('<p class="error-keyup-1 errorStyle centerText">cRAP</p>').appendTo('#enterRequestDataSection');
  }
  if ($('#requestedInput').val().length==0) {
    $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();   
   }
  });
 
});    // End of JQUERY CODE
```

```html
<div id="requestActionTypeRow">
 <ul class="requestActionType"> 
  <li class="ax_text_field"><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="radioAcctInp" checked="checked" >Account&nbspNumber</li> 
  <li class="ax_text_field"><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="radioSwiftInp" >Show&nbspalphaNumeric&nbspAddress</li>  
 </ul>     
</div> 
 
<div id="enterRequestDataSection">
 <ul class="enterRequestDataType">  
  <li><input type="text" id="requestedInput" name="acctNumber" value="Update Address using Account Number" maxlength="10" class="inputNumTextBox keyup-numeric"></li>
  <li id="showDetails" name="showDetails" value="Show Details" onclick="validateAcctMaint(this.form)">Show Details</li>
  <li class="addNewLink">Add New</li>  
 </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: Try with $(document).on('click', "text.tabclick", function() {}); as classes added dynamically

Comment: The events you added earlier do not magically bind and unbind based on adding/removing classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#radio1").click(function() {
        $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();
        $("#requestedInput").val("Update Address using Account Number").attr('name','acctNumber').attr('maxlength','10');
        $("#requestedInput").removeClass().addClass('inputNumTextBox keyup-numeric');
    });     
    $("#radio2").click(function() {     
        $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();
        $("#requestedInput").val("Update Account Number using Address").attr('name', 'Address').attr('maxlength','23');
        $("#requestedInput").removeClass().addClass('inputNumTextBox keyup-charNumOnly');
    } );

$(document).on('keyup', "#requestedInput.keyup-numeric", function() {
        $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
        var AcctReg9 = /^9/;
        if(!numericReg.test(inputVal)) {    
            $('<p class="error-keyup-1 errorStyle centerText">Numeric characters only</p>').appendTo('#enterRequestDataSection');
        }
        if(!AcctReg9.test(inputVal)) {  
            $('<p class="error-keyup-1 errorStyle centerText">Accounts Start with 9 .... Required</p>').appendTo('#enterRequestDataSection');
        }
        if ($('#requestedInput').val().length==0) {
                $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();          
            }
        }); 


$(document).on('keyup', "#requestedInput.keyup-charNumOnly", function() {
        alert('keyup-charNumOnly I'); 
        $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();
        var inputVal = $(this).val();   
        var characterReg = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
        if(!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {  
            alert('keyup-charNumOnly II'); 
            $('<p class="error-keyup-1 errorStyle centerText">cRAP</p>').appendTo('#enterRequestDataSection');
        }
        if ($('#requestedInput').val().length==0) {
                $('p.error-keyup-1').remove();          
            }
        });

});    // End of JQUERY CODE
```

Comment: Thanks To all. Your suggestions worked. I'm in the middle of reading my first JQUERY Book ( Head First ) , so hopefully I will have a better understanding soon.

Answer (score 0):

The keyUpCharNumOnly class doesn't exists when the keyup event is bound after document(ready(.

You will want to use:

```
$('.keyup-charNumOnly').on('keyup', function() {
```